# Непостижимая ошибка

Tags: c++, сортировка, stl, vector

Есть класс Флешка с полями фирма, тип, память, количество и дата производства

```
//...
private:
    string _firm;
    string _type;
    int _memoryGB;
    int _quantity;
    string _date;
};
```

Есть класс Список флешек

```
class FlashList
{
public:
    FlashList(vector<Flashka> list);
//...
private:
    vector<Flashka> _list;
};
```

Нужна функция для сортировки флешек по названию фирмы

```
//...
    vector<Flashka> FirmSort(string firm)
    {
        vector<Flashka> result;

        for (auto i = 0; i < _list.size(); ++i)
            if (firm == _list[i].getFirm())
                result.push_back(_list[i]);
        return result;
    }
```

Использую гугл-тесты

```
TEST(FlashList, Sort)
{
    Flashka a("HP", "NOR", 32, 56, "21.11.2017");
    Flashka b("HP", "NAND", 64, 48, "01.11.2017");
    Flashka c("Kingston", "NOR", 16, 24, "02.11.2017");
    Flashka d("Transcend", "NAND", 16, 48, "21.11.2017");

    vector<Flashka> v;
    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(b);
    v.push_back(c);
    v.push_back(d);
    FlashList List(v);

    vector<Flashka> trew;
    trew.push_back(a);
    trew.push_back(b);

    EXPECT_TRUE(trew == List.FirmSort("HP"));
}
```

выдаёт следующее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как побороть?

Comment: Стандартный алгоритм `sort()` с соответствующим компаратором... В вашей `FirmSort` я вижу **фильтрацию**, но никак не сортировку. Что до невозможности скомпилировать - а вы определили оператор `==` для флешек? Как ему сравнивать-то, если вы не сказали, как это делается?

Comment: оператор == для флешек есть, работает (тесты есть),  да, мне нужна скорее фильтрация

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки (есть в окне Output), а не скриншот.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция реализует стандартный (правда, только начиная с C++11) алгоритм [copy_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/). Там же и пример. В котором, правда, преждевременная оптимизация - вектор-приемник создатся со стартовым размером, потом обрезается, вместо использовагия std::back_inserter() в пустой вектор.